# Find all sequences and other schema objects owned not by certain user

Tags: postgresql, sequence, owner, acl

How can I find all sequences (and more widely - all objects in given schema), which are owned not by certain user, on PostgreSQL (10-15)?

I found such query:

```sql
SELECT relname, relacl 
FROM pg_class pgc
WHERE relkind = 'S'
AND relacl is not null
AND relnamespace IN (
    SELECT oid
    FROM pg_namespace
    WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
    AND nspname != 'information_schema'
)
and relname = 'my_table_id_seq';
```

But any further attempts to work with a `relacl` column fails with errors, f.e.:

```sql
array_to_string(array(relacl))
```

gives an error:

`[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "relacl"`

Also I've found a `explodeacl` function, which returns rowset of `aclitem[]`, but I cannot get how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`relacl` stores the access control list of an object, **not** the owner. The owner of a row in `pg_class` is stored in `relowner`. So to find all sequences not owned by a specific user, use:

```
SELECT relname, relacl 
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relkind = 'S'
AND relowner <> 'that_user'::regrole --<< "not owed by "that_user"
AND relnamespace IN (
    SELECT oid
    FROM pg_namespace
    WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
    AND nspname != 'information_schema'
)
and relname = 'my_table_id_seq';
```